# How to block access to databases except those permitted to access SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

In SQL Server, there is a user `user1` who can access tables in databases `AA` and `BB`.

Then I want `user1` not to access all other databases except `AA`, `BB`.

That is, `user1` should not access any tables in any other databases except `AA` and `BB`.

Comment: Google something like "SQL server user mapping". It is too broad question to be answered in the QA format of StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, you have a **login** at the server level - and then you can define a **user** for that login in each database where that login should have access to. So if `user1` should have access only to `AA` and `BB` - just create users for `user1` only in `AA` and `BB` and that login will not be able to access any other databases on that server instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly deny permissions ,if they don't have access,you can ignore

```
--create role in database
    create role test1

    --grant access on table t to test1
    GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[T]  TO [test1]
    GO

    --you can even define column level permissions ,now users assigned to role test1 ---can view only column A of table T
    GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[T] ([A]) TO [test1]

    --finally assign user john to role

    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'test1', 'john';
```

Comment: Hello, I am checking your solution. Thank you for your kindness. Have a nice day~

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

[SQL Server : can you limit access to only one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787047/sql-server-can-you-limit-access-to-only-one-table)

```
exec sp_msforeachtable "DENY SELECT ON '?' TO [username];"
GO

GRANT SELECT ON [schemaName].[tableName] to [username]
Go
```

Comment: Hello, I am checking your solution too. Thank you for  your sweetness. Have a nice day also to you~!!

Comment: No need to deny - unless the "standard setup" in you world is to allow anyone access to anything.