# SQL Server permissions to only one table for specific users

Tags: sql, security, permissions, roles

I have a database with many users who have access to all tables within the DB.  There is one table that I would like to restrict access to only a specific few users.  So basically granting table access to some while removing table access to the rest.  Any thoughts on best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always DENY SELECT to all users on that table, and then grant it by person for the few you do want to have access to it.

[DENY Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx)

This question may also help you: [SQL Server : can you limit access to only one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787047/sql-server-can-you-limit-access-to-only-one-table)