# How do I prevent a specific user to access a specific table in my SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a database called `MyDatabase` which contains several tables. I have a user called `User1` who has read permissions on the database.

Assuming I want to prevent `User1` from accessing a table called `tbl1` (that is, to query or view this table), how can I do it?

Searching on `StackOverflow`, I have come across this question: [SQL Server : can you limit access to only one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787047/sql-server-can-you-limit-access-to-only-one-table)

Going by the accepted answer in that question, my SQL query would stand like this:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable "DENY SELECT ON tbl1 TO [User1];"
GO
```

Is this the right way to do it? Or is there a more efficient way of tackling this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use sp_msforeachtable. Only one table is involved so you can accomplish your task by issuing

```
DENY SELECT ON tableName TO [userName]
```

.. or

```
REVOKE SELECT ON OBJECT::[shemaName].[tableName] TO [userName]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will just say for future readers that if you want to allow selects the syntax is "GRANT SELECT ON [tablename] TO [user]